# Parser Generator or Library that Supports Suffix Agreement

Tags: java, parsing, nlp, parser-generator

I'm working on a syntactic parser for some language. But this language requires suffix agreement highly. For example in English a verb must agree with pronoun as I,we,you-do or he,she,it,this-does etc. In this language a verb has different forms for each pronoun. I know in literature this is handled by unification method. But I couldn't find any implementation of it in Java. I also researched Stanford parser and ANTLR but I couldn’t find any evidence that they support suffix agreement.

So which tool or lib. would you offer me in this situation?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't seen a parser than can do this directly, though we did use a unification parser in a grad school class I had. Unfortunately, the name escapes me and it was really old even then.  I'm 99% sure it wasn't open source.

You could try the [KIMMO](http://www.sil.org/pckimmo/) parser, though I have never used it, so can't attest to its applicability to your problem.